# Getting specific information in controller?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

im having issues with my controller and getting data within it. My issue is that when i get my team like so:

```
$team = Team::where('join_number', '=', $data['team'])->get();
```

i cant seem too access it by going

```
$team->join_request_needed = 'True'
```

for example? If i just die dump

```
$team->join_request_needed
```

i get a 'Property [join_request_needed] does not exist on this collection instance'.
How can i access this data? If i die dump $team i get this; so it gets the data?

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#282 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Team {#291 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "sqlite"
      #table: "teams"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:8 [▶]
      #original: array:8 [▼
        "id" => "1"
        "user_id" => "1"
        "name" => "team1"
        "description" => null
        "join_request_needed" => "0"
        "join_number" => "1574832472024"
        "created_at" => "2019-11-27 05:27:52"
        "updated_at" => "2019-11-27 22:46:55"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my entire function (only rough so far since im stuck on getting the data):

```
public function check() {
    $data = request()->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'team' => ['required', 'alpha_num', 'exists:teams,join_number']
    ]);

    $team = Team::where('join_number', '=', $data['team'])->get();

    if ($team->join_request_needed = 'True') {
        if (Member::where('email', '=', $data['email'])->count() > 0) {
            $member = Member::where('email', '=', $data['email']);
            if ($member->approved = 'True') {
                // member has been accepted
                return view('portal.members.answer', [
                    'team' => $team
                ]); // questions
            } else {
                // member has not been accepted
                dd('member has not been accepted');
                return view(''); // waiting screen
            }
        } else {
            // create a join request for the member
            $team->member()->create([
                'email' => $data['email']
            ]);
            return view(''); // waiting screen
        }
    } else if(Member::where('email', '=', $data['email'])->count() > 0) {
        // no join request needed, member already exists
        return view('portal.members.answer', [
            'team' => $team
        ]); // questions
    } else {
        // no join request needed, need to create member
        dd($team);
        $team->member()->create([
            'email' => $data['email']
        ]);
        return view('portal.members.answer', [
            'team' => $team
        ]); // questions
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your if is wrong, you are setting the information on `$team->join_request_needed` with the value `True`, this return true because you can set the value on the property. `if ($team->join_request_needed = 'True') {` is the point that you are setting the value. Note that you need to put `== ` (two equals) to compare. And compare with `false` and `true` without the single quotes. The single quotes indicates that your variable is a string, not boolean

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes sorry, updated the question. im getting an error for just '$team->join_request_needed' so that doesnt matter yet

Comment: To access you need to call on the first position, the get() function returns a collection. If you call `$team[0]->join_request_needed` should work.

Comment: but team is a collection of teams, wouldnt it be enough to just get the first team out with first()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team is in your case a collection of Teams, therefor you can utilise the querybuilder method `first()`

```
$team = Team::where('join_number', '=', $data['team'])->first();
```

Since the way queries work, calling get on the Query Builder will always return a collection. If you want single objects `first()` or `find()` is the options.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the collection of `Team` with `join_number = $data['team']`
You need to loop first for the `$team`. But if you only want to have one $team that has a `join_number = $data['team']` you should do `first()` instead of `get()`